# Encrypting data to a third party

Tags: email, encoding

I need to send a PDF to person B through person A, without person A being able to access it and i can not contact person B. Currently i only have person B's email address.

so the email will go from me -> A -> B

Answer (score -1):

You can not disguise or impose and send email from someone else email address, IF that mail server does not allow sending emails without credentials (username,  password) .  Example: if you want to send mail from xyz.gmail.com, then you need xyz, credentials.

Copying text from comments so that this doesn't get down voted as non related answer.

Based on your latest edit,
One possible solution is to password protect your PDF and send it to A and ask him to send it to B.  The password should be some thing like a pin that only B will know without you sending it to B

Comment: no you see, i am going to send it to person A but he/she must not be able to access it. They will then send it to person B.

Comment: Only possible solution is to password protect your PDF and send it to A and ask him to send it to B.  The password should be some thing like a pin that only B should know

Comment: May be like B's dob + PIN

Comment: Thanks to one who down voted this without a proper reason